# React UI and Node.js/Express app served/monitored with webpack

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, webpack

I am new to `React` and `Node`, trying to setup an environment to work.

I worked a little with `Node.js`/`Express` before and I used `nodemon` to monitor file changes and restart my app.

Also I recently started to work with `React` and I use `webpack dev server` (specifically `webpack-dev-server --content-base src --inline --hot --history-api-fallback`) setup that monitors file changes and reload the UI.

**The problem**

Now, I want to tie it together.

First solution I found was: Start my `node app` on specific port, say 3000 then start `webpack dev server` on 8080 port and `proxy` requests to specific urls to my `backend app`.

```
devServer: {
    proxy: {
        '/backend-api/': {
            target: {
                "host": "localhost",
                "protocol": 'http:',
                "port": 3000
            },
            ignorePath: false,
            changeOrigin: true,
            secure: false
        }
    }
},
```

It should work but i do not feel right starting two servers for single application.

Is there any way (and simple example i could understand) to start **single** server that would **serve both**: a `server side app` and `React UI`?

And of course, it should track file changes and restart server app if server code changes OR reload UI if client side code changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use webpack through Express middleware using this package: https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-middleware

You can use it by simply adding it to the app:

```
var webpackMiddleware = require("webpack-dev-middleware");
app.use(webpackMiddleware(webpack({/* webpack options */})));
```

In addition there's a package that builds on this to offer hotloading and "Create React App" style terminal display: https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-express-middleware

Comment: Thank you! Sorry it took so long to mark your answer :)